# PHP - Execute a specific php code when clicking a link

Tags: php, web, hyperlink, click

I'm currently working on a website and I would like to be able to do the following:

- when clicking one of the links from the sideMenu the only thing I would like to change would be the content of my contentMain div and nothing else(page layout/design/etc)

Could anybody give me some general pointers on how I could achieve this in php?

Thank You in advance :D

Comment: Definitely look into using Ajax as it is perfect for things like this.

Comment: Ajax, jQuery, Javascript are your friends - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a client-side change that cannot be accomplished using PHP. PHP is evaluated on the server-side, so once the page is loaded for the user, it has no control over what the user sees (unless you use client-side code to call PHP).

To accomplish this, you will need to use Javascript and/or jQuery.

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/

**jQuery**: http://jquery.org/

Comment: Or Prototype, or mootools, or...  (+1, btw)

Answer (score 1):

iFrame, frameset or AJAX all work for your case depending on what you are actually trying to achieve.

For AJAX calls (the most modern way out of the three that relies on Javascript) you can use a library such as jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax for this one. Using jQuery to detect the click on the link or use normal JavaScript onClick function. Then do the things like you want.

```
<a href="" id="my_link">My link<a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('#my_link').click(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'ajax page need to be called',
                success: function(data) {
                     //do your operations on success
                }
           });
         });
   });
</script>
```

You can get more details on :

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Hope this helps you